# Flutter graber widget for DraggbleScrollableWidget

Tags: flutter, modalbottomsheet

I want to achieve this kind of a Grabber widget or smth like that, that will be above DraggbleScrollableWidget. And how to make it follow the draggblescrollablesheet's drag behavior?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJyFN.png)

I tried custom_modal_sheet library but it's not what i actually need. Because this library doesnot provides options I need.

Comment: Which options do you need? You don't provide enough information .. Nevertheless i guess https://pub.dev/packages/snapping_sheet_2 could help you out.